# python loading package global config externally

Tags: python

I have a package called lib. What I want to achieve is to load some config from  a yaml file in the main.py and set the package config to that where the package config would be globally accessible.
Note that I do not want to load the yaml file from within my package, but want to load it in main.py and pass it in.
The problem is that the fire.py still sees an empty dictionary.
Please explain why and how to fix it.

```
.
└───lib
└───lib/__init__.py
└───lib/fire.py
└───config.yaml
└───main.py
```

main.py:

```
import yaml
import os
import lib.fire as fire
import lib
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file= open("%s/config.yaml" % BASE_DIR, 'r')
config = yaml.load(stream)
lib.set_config(config)
file.close()
fire.start()
```

**init**.py:

```
config = {}

def set_config(data):
    global config
    config = data
```

fire.py

```
from . import config

def start():
    print config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import `lib.fire` it fetches config from `__init__.py`.  At that point it's `{}`.

If you're going to do this, you need to import `lib.fire` after you've called `set_config`.

```
import lib
lib.set_config(config)
import lib.fire as fire
fire.start()
```

To avoid having to make the imports in the right order, in `fire.py`:

```
import lib

def start():
    print lib.config
```

You imported the lib object, and you changed it later, but you've still got the right object when you ask it for the config.

Generally, I'd try not to have global variable, but that means passing the config object around to where you need it.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there a better design to achieve the same outcome?